# mpi4py spawn communication between processes fails on windows 7

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

My goal is to have a python script be able to start an other python script on different processes, i.e. I want to spreadthe script over n processes. To try to achieve that I am trying to run the mpi4py spawn example given in the documentation (see http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html). But this example fails with the message:

> At least one pair of MPI processes are unable to reach each other for
>   MPI communications. This means that ... This error can sometimes be
>   the result of forgetting to specify the 'self' BTL. ... Your MPI job
>   is now going to abort.

my installation is on a windows 7 machine with openMPI 1.6.1 and the latest mpi4py installation.

The code, in my case is:
master.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy
import sys

comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable,
                           args=['worker.py'],
                           maxprocs=5)

N = numpy.array(100, 'i')
comm.Bcast([N, MPI.INT], root=MPI.ROOT)
PI = numpy.array(0.0, 'd')
comm.Reduce(None, [PI, MPI.DOUBLE],
            op=MPI.SUM, root=MPI.ROOT)
print(PI)

comm.Disconnect()
```

worker.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

comm = MPI.Comm.Get_parent()
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

N = numpy.array(0, dtype='i')
comm.Bcast([N, MPI.INT], root=0)
h = 1.0 / N; s = 0.0
for i in range(rank, N, size):
    x = h * (i + 0.5)
    s += 4.0 / (1.0 + x**2)
PI = numpy.array(s * h, dtype='d')
comm.Reduce([PI, MPI.DOUBLE], None,
            op=MPI.SUM, root=0)

comm.Disconnect()
```

the line producing the error is:

```
comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable,
                           args=['worker.py'],
                           maxprocs=5)
```

The command to run the script is in the cmd prompt:

```
mpirun -n 1 python.exe master.py
```